# NSURLSessionDownloadTask Delegates not calling didWriteData method

Tags: ios, download, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm starting to implement a download method using NSURLSession and successfully downloaded different files from multiple request. But now I wanted to add a progress track, however the delegates for download progress is not being triggered.

Here is my code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask = [defaultSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * __nullable location,
                                                                 NSURLResponse * __nullable response, NSError * __nullable error) {

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docPath contents:data attributes:nil];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {

NSDictionary *notificationDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:docPath,@"docPath", item, @"item", nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"openFile" object:nil userInfo:notificationDic];

}

}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

I have the NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate on my header file.

I needed to use completion handler to be able to perform different tasks with the file.

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but I'd advise against using `createFileAtPath`. One of the benefits of `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is that it streams the download directly to persistent storage, a benefit that you're giving up by then using `dataWithContentsOfURL` and `createFileAtPath:contents:`. Instead, I might suggest bypassing the loading it into a `NSData` and use `NSFileManager` method `moveItemAtURL` to move it from `location` to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPath]`.

Comment: @Rob Will do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `downloadTaskWithRequest` rendition without the `completionHandler` parameter, then the progress delegate methods will be called. Obviously, you'll have to move the code currently in the `completionHandler` block into the `didFinishDownloadingToURL` method. But if you do this, you'll see `didWriteData` called.

Comment: I was just was the completion handler because my 'docPath' is different from file to file and I can also have multiple file downloading at the same time, so it made it easier for me to handle the response. But I'll try to use didFinishDownloadingToURL.
Thank you.

Comment: Yep, it's annoying, but that's what you'll have to do in order to enjoy `didWriteData` callback, too. When `NSURLSessionTask` is created, it is assigned a `taskIdentifier`, and you can build a dictionary of destination `docPath` values using the `taskIdentifier` as the key. Or, alternatively, in `didFinishDownloadingToURL`, you can retrieve the `originalRequest`, and use some parameter of that request (e.g. the `URL`) as the key for your dictionary. It's tiresome, but it's how we do it. Or you can use something like AFNetworking, that takes care of this headache for you.

Comment: Thank you! Nowhere did I find this answer. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initiate your download with:

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

And implement the delegate method for your progress:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                                       didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
                                  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
                          totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
```

And since you need to perform various tasks when finished, you should also implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                          didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location;
```

Essentially, the completion handler routines are "convenience" routines to quickly perform the task and then when finished, perform the completion handler. But they don't call the other delegate routines.

Comment: I was just using the completion handler because my 'docPath' is different from file to file and I can also have multiple file downloading at the same time, so it made it easier for me to handle the response. But I'll try to use didFinishDownloadingToURL.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I conform my class with `URLSessionDelegate` instead of `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`. Even if I was implementing the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` methods.